# Filtering data frame rows with regex

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my data frame:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'Period':['Group 1 vs Group 2:Change at 3 mo', 'Group 1:Change at 3 mo', 'Group 1 vs Group 2:Change at 3 mo', 'Group 2:Change at 3 mo'], 'estimate':[20, 21, 19, 18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I need to get only rows that in variable `Period` **do not** contain anywhere `Group 1 vs Group 2`. I tried this code:

```
df = df.loc[df['Period'].str.contains(pat = '(?!Group 1 vs Group 2)', regex = True)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it does not filters rows and I am getting original df as a result. How to fix my code so I will get only rows that in variable `Period` **do not** contain anywhere `Group 1 vs Group 2`?

Comment: `df[~df['Period'].str.contains(r'Group 1 vs Group 2')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `str.match`

```
df[~df.Period.str.match('Group 1 vs Group 2')]
Out[85]: 
                   Period  estimate
1  Group 1:Change at 3 mo        21
3  Group 2:Change at 3 mo        18
```